# NAS and other LAN devices periodically disappear from File Explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows, lan, nas

My Windows 10 PC can ping my NAS and it can access the NAS web UI by typing the NAS LAN IP into the browser. However, it is hit or miss whether I can see the NAS file system in the File Explorer Network View. Sometimes it is there and most of the time it is not. It did not used to be like this - it was there all the time and I had it mapped to a drive letter. What changed? I have no idea.

Not only my NAS is affected by this, but it's the thing that causes me the most grief because I don't typically need to access my other devices from this PC. Disabling/enabling the network interface doesn't help. Rebooting the NAS seems to help sometimes but that's fairly annoying. Rebooting the PC doesn't seem to help. Sometimes this PC does not even see itself in the Network view. Right at the moment it does but I have no confidence that it will continue to do so. Refreshing the view doesn't seem to change things in any consistent way.

I have no other apparent issues with Windows 10 as regards the LAN, internet connection, etc.

I am on a wired LAN and Belkin N150 router.

For comparison, my Macbook consistently does see the NAS in Finder over wireless to the same router.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IP address of the NAS you could try to address it directly by its IP address in Windows File Explorer. Let say that the IP address of the NAS is 192.168.0.10. In that case it can be refered to as \\192.168.0.10 in Windows File Explorer. You should also be able to connect a drive letter to a known share by following this syntax: \\192.168.0.10\sharename

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this scenario for a number weeks.  I've gone through all of the recommended tweaks and fixes and what I found was absurd.   Yes, turning on SMB is required, but the fix was stupid.   I went to settings / accounts / sign in by PIN and turned it off.   I'm not kidding.  I rebooted my machine and all of the shares came back.   They've stayed.   I signed into Windows through my Microsoft account password. This also makes sense as why I've been able to see the NAS devices through my Apple computers.  Just not Microsoft ones.   I haven't had an issue since.  This also means that face recognition logins are also off the table as well as it requires a PIN to work. No more disappearances.